# Can keywords stuffed in a div that is out of the visible part of the screen be harmful?

Tags: seo

Going through a friend's site, I found a div stuffed with keywords and links to different pages on the site. The div has attributes top:-10000px;left:-10000px; which keep it out of display but visible to bots.
He says that they have helped him get a better ranking. It's definitely black hat, but is it okay to keep the div or should it be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's harmful and dumb. This is a great way to get banned. It's only a matter of time before your friend is caught.

Comment: "This is a great way to get banned." - banned from where?

Comment: From the search engines indexes, especially Google.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing outdated SEO tactics is not "black hat". Search engines like Google are well aware of keyword stuffing, especially when they are made invisible to humans whether they are moved off-screen or made the same color as the background.

**Yes**, it is harmful.

He needs to modernize his game and stop stealing pages from the book of 2001.